# Writing retrying mechanism to print out log

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am writing a retrying mechanism. At the moment we get a lot of connection issues and they are false postivies and the connection generally gets back online after 300ish milliseconds. So I wrote the following in order for the code to write an error log if the connection is still not back up after 2 seconds from the initial disconnection:

```
   private final long threadSleeper;
   private final long durationOfTEst;
   private long timeOfError =0;
   private boolean firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds = true;

   public Session(long threadSleeper, boolean firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds, long durationOfTest)
   {
      this.durationOfTEst = durationOfTest;
      this.threadSleeper = threadSleeper;
      this.firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds = firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds;
      if(!firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds)
      {
         timeOfError = System.currentTimeMillis()-10000;
      }
   }

   public void retry() throws Exception
   {
      long exectTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() - exectTime < durationOfTEst)
      {
         if (firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds)
         {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeOfError >= 2000 && firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds)
            {
               firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds = false;
            }
            timeOfError = System.currentTimeMillis();
            firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds = false;
         } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeOfError >= 2000 && !firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds)
         {
            System.out.println(timeOfError);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds = true;
            timeOfError = 0L;
            System.out.println("THIS IS THE EXCEPTION");
         }

         System.out.println("Thread Sleeping. Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
         Thread.sleep(threadSleeper);
      }
   }
```

And these are my tests:

```
   @Test
   public void shouldPrintOut3ExceptionsIfFromTheFirstErrorInADurationOf6() throws Exception
   {
      Session session = new Session( 300, true, 6500);

      session.retry();
   }

   @Test
   public void shouldPrintOutNoExceptionsIfConnectionComesBackUpWithin2Seconds() throws Exception
   {
      Session session = new Session( 100, true, 1300);

      session.retry();
   }

   @Test
   public void shouldPrintOut3ExceptionIfContinuingOnFromState() throws Exception
   {
      Session session = new Session( 300, false, 6000);

      session.retry();
   }

   @Test
   public void shouldPrintOut1ExceptionIn3Seconds() throws Exception
   {
      Session session = new Session( 100, false, 3000);

      session.retry();
   }
```

Now it's not really perfect. The while loop is there just for the benefit of unit test for the time being. I believe that it can be refactored more better but there's a few edge cases I'm struggling to cater in:

The reason for the `firstTimeErroringAfter2Sconds` variable in the onstructor is to simulate the scenario where if the connection comes back online whilst the code in the if statement changes it to false.

At the moment, the test that seems to be failing is the shouldPrintOut1ExceptionIn3Seconds. It should print out 1 but prints out 2 at the moment. I know why it does since `timeOfError` is set to be more than 10 seconds (in the constructor) hence it executes it but but I'm struggling to code it to print out once. Any suggestions?

These are pretty much all primitive data types so you can paste this and have a go on your local machines. and btw, `timeOfError = System.currentTimeMillis()-10000;` is configurable. You can make it be

Comment: I know the question is about the unit testing, but have you considered using spring retry library that already implements the retry functionality https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: @MarkBramnik I'm actually adding this functionality into an open source library that we use. So Can't use spring unfortuneabtly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you perform a network call (or a DBCall) you configure it with a timeout.

You don't need to loop and block the Thread with Thread.sleep. You can just configure your timeout to be 2 seconds. If it reconnect faster, there no error and you are done.

If it still not connected, you get an exception from your call, you catch it, log whatever you want and call it a day.